# How to create a QGIS Action which loads a raster?

Tags: qgis, python

I am following an article here:[Actions HowTo](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Actions-HowTo-td4534256.html) , specifically the piece about an action to load a raster:

```
Python type
    Add Raster Layer
            qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer('PATH_FILE','NAME_FILE_IN_QGIS')
```

Can anyone advise what i need to do to open a raster based on a value in the vector table (essentially I have a grid with a field containing a field of Grid_Ref for all items where a raster image exists).

I have been fiddling with the example above and got as far as an Action of Type Python, Named OpenRaster, with the following action:

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer('E:\Plot Sheet Devt\1974-1984\1250k\' + "Grid_Ref" + '.TIF',"Grid_Ref")
```

The Python error that I am getting on running this is

> File "", line 1
>       qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer('E:\Plot Sheet Devt\1974-1984\1250k\' + "Grid_Ref" + '.TIF',"Grid_Ref")
>                                                                                                              ^
>
> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

How should I go about forming the open 'PATH_FILE' and 'NAME_FILE_IN_QGIS' so that it picks the information from the Grid_Ref field in the underlying vector data?

As always, thanks for your time

Mark

Comment: Which QGIS version?

Comment: @NathanW - currently looking at 1.8, but will have to replicate in 2 when I get up and running on that

Comment: Great Action.
I'm using it.
Is it possible to assign the Coordinate reference systems and to build pyramids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this by following this [article](http://linfiniti.com/2012/03/a-python-layer-action-to-open-a-wikipedia-page-in-qgis/) and adapting it to fit my requirements, and have ended up setting the command as:

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer('E:\\Plot Sheet Devt\\1974-1984\\1250k\\[% Grid_Ref %].TIF', '[% Grid_Ref %]')
```

therefore I am using the format

> [% attributename %]

to collect the value of an attribute where the action is used.

Also I have corrected my non-escaped backslashes from original post.