# QGIS Action which load .asc

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, actions

I have a grid layer (lidar_cortina) with "NAME" and "percorso"(path) coloumns:

[image]

I'm trying to write an QGIS action that loads file .asc from a grid layer.

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("[%percorso%]", "[%NAME%]")
```

but It doesn't work and the message "the command can not be executed" appears

If I use the console loading one .asc it works well

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("//rvphnas02pw/Remote_Sensing/Lidar/2017_Lidar_Cortina/SECONDA_CONSEGNA/Lidar/DTM/P740451578_0101_100_DTM.asc", "P740451578_0101_100")
```

Any suggestion.

UPDATE

If I use this code, it works well:

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer('//rvphnas02pw/Remote_Sensing/Lidar/2017_Lidar_Cortina/SECONDA_CONSEGNA/Lidar/DTM/[%NAME%]_DTM.asc', '[%NAME%]')
```

---

Using the code of: [Developing QGIS Action which loads a raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225459/developing-qgis-action-which-loads-a-raster)
I have write an other qgis action to open .asc file from a grid layer with "NAME" column:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo,QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('lidar_cortina')[0]
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group_name = "lidar"
group = root.findGroup(group_name)
if group == None:
    group = root.addGroup("lidar")
else:
    pass
fileName ='D:/GIS/Dati/lidar/[% NAME %]_DTM.asc'
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = '[% NAME %]'
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
crs.createFromSrid(32632) 
rlayer.setCrs(crs)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer, False)
group.insertChildNode(-1, QgsLayerTreeLayer(rlayer))
```

but It doesn't work.

[image: Error Message]

Using python console to open one .asc file with the same code of error message, It works:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo,QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('lidar_cortina_prova')[0]
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group_name = "lidar"
group = root.findGroup(group_name)
if group == None:
    group = root.addGroup("lidar")
else:
    pass

fileName ='D:/GIS/Dati/lidar/P740451578_0101_100_DTM.asc'
baseName='P740451578_0101_100'
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
crs.createFromSrid(32632) 
rlayer.setCrs(crs)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer, False)
group.insertChildNode(-1, QgsLayerTreeLayer(rlayer))
```

I can't understand
Any suggestion is welcome.

UPDATE 2

changing the path with the suggestion in comment of @lrssvt, I obtain the same error:

[image]

Comment: Maybe a subtility with the unc naming of the files ? Did u try with the full paths ?

Comment: "percorso" is a full network path

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to how the path of the file is interpreted from python.

I guess you can do the following edit to solve the issue:

from:

```
fileName = 'D:/GIS/Dati/lidar/P740451578_0101_100_DTM.asc'
```

to:

```py
fileName = 'D:\\GIS\\Dati\\lidar\\P740451578_0101_100_DTM.asc'
```

If you have the path in attribute table you can edit it using the field calculator with the expression:

`replace("path", '/', '\\\\')`

Comment: With your suggestion  I obtain the same error. Look the update 2 in question.

Comment: Please, could you provide what the log message says by clicking the icon to the bottom right of the status bar?

Comment: No log message. The only error message is that of the image. I don't understand I use this action with a lot of other file directory.